# Bluetooth sound quality with phone is much better than sound quality with laptop

Tags: headphones, quality

So I have the Samsung Galaxy S10 and the latest Dell Inspiron - when I use my headset (Beoplay H9) with my smartphone (call via skype/whatsapp/viber) the quality is really good, but when I use the headset with my laptop, the quality is really poor, as if A2DP was not enabled. I wonder if I should try a USB Bluetooth dongle, as my headset supports aptX LL and cvc - maybe this will help improve the quality in Ubuntu?

I wonder if there is somebody here who has expensive headphones and can help me out use them with Linux. Thanks in advance!

Response from `sudo lspci -v` excerpting only the wireless portion shows the [Intel Wireless-AC 9650](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/wireless/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-9560.html) is used, which supports [Bluetooth 5](https://www.howtogeek.com/343718/whats-different-in-bluetooth-5.0/) :

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at ed31c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Also please run `pactl list | grep -i module-bluetooth-discover` (as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1199059) and advise the results. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question.

Comment: @K7AAY i dont think this will help